# Expression for an 'end-to-end product development process'

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, terminology

I am looking for a single word or a phrase that can effectively describe:

> the start to end, from-the-ground-up, development of something new.

That is, the process of coming up with the idea, designing an actual product and building it.

Comment: Evolution? I cant think of any word which better describes it.

Comment: [Scrum](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/scrum)'s a nice word ... Sense 4 is  “In Agile software development, a daily meeting in which each developer describes what they have been doing, what they plan to do next, and any impediments to progress” but *[R&D](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%26D)* probably is a more general and appropriate term

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Do you mean the ongoing process or a single instance of the process, for a single product?

Answer (score 1):

You already have the official term for that: ***[New product development](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_product_development)***.

> In business  and engineering, new product development (NPD) is the complete process of bringing a new product to market … the idea generation, product design and detail engineering …

See also on the same page, [The Eight Stages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_product_development#The_eight_stages): Idea Generation, Idea Screening, Concept Development & Testing, Business Analysis, Beta Testing & Market Testing, Technical Implementation, Commercialization, Pricing.

Further Reading: [entrepreneur.com](http://www.entrepreneur.com/encyclopedia/product-development)

Answer (score 0):

You may refer SDLC (Software Development Life Cycle)

Comment: Nah, that's Synchronous Data Link Control.

Answer (score 0):

A set of relevant terms use the root "cycle":

- Product cycle
- Lifecycle
- Product lifecycle
- Development cycle

Wikipedia seems to prefer product lifecycle management (PLM):

> In industry, [product lifecycle management (PLM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_cycle) is the process of managing the entire lifecycle of a product from inception, through engineering design and manufacture, to service and disposal of manufactured products. PLM integrates people, data, processes and business systems and provides a product information backbone for companies and their extended enterprise.

If you need keep the character count low, an industry standard term would be "PLM" for the hands-on management; otherwise I suggest "lifecycle" for the description of the process itself.

Comment: To me, the word "cycle" gives off the impression of this being a habitual, and automated process, while I am looking for something that emphasises the creative component of it. Management does not sound right in this context either; it seems to suggest there's a system already in place and you're just marshaling the different parts. I like "development cycle", but need something else in the place of "cycle".

Comment: @Karnn: "development cycle" is used heavily in software engineering. The "lifecycle" of a product seems pretty close to your intended meaning. There isn't anything about "cycle" that implies habitual or automated. These are terms already in heavy usage and are not ambiguous. They very much match your intended meaning.

Answer (score 0):

> - [**Workflow**](http://gog.is/define+workflow)
>
> > The sequence of industrial, administrative, or other processes through which a piece of work passes from initiation to completion.

It sounds quite similar to your description.

> *"The workflow of creating the end product began at idea generation, describe .. dadida .. and culminated in the manufacturing of this wonderful [object everybody will want]."*

Answer (score 0):

You might say 'complete' or a synonym thereof. Here are some example phrases:

> 1. Here at the **job-lot** construction company we do the **whole shebang**.
> 2. We offer a **total** development service.
> 3. Your request is so unique we're going to have to do it all **from scratch**.
> 4. I was really pleased with their work, they gave it the **full-treatment**.

Answer (score -1):

**creation**

the action or process of bringing something into existence. [Google]

Comment: This has been brought up before, but the rules stayed in place for a reason. You can, and are supposed to, include the definition or examples. It's not that hard, either. And in any case the point of the character limit is not that people circumvent it by saying "there is a character limit". Just a tiny bit more creativity is all you need.